# JQuery .load - Not working when calling button is in form tags

Tags: jquery, forms, load

I have a simple JQuery load satement in a function [ ignore the naming]. As it is presented it does not work. When the form tags are removed it does. Appreciate your advice on why this occurs..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HTML 5 Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$("document").ready(function() {

$('#getCalc').bind('click' , getPlainHTMLfromServer );
}); // end ready

function getPlainHTMLfromServer() {
$('#content').load("plainHTML.html");

}// end getPlainHTMLfromServer()

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<form>
<button id="getCalc">Double</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prevent the default action of the *submit event*, by default the type attribute of the button is submit:

```
function getPlainHTMLfromServer(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#content').load("plainHTML.html");
}
```

Or add `type='button'` attribute to the button element:

```
<button id="getCalc" type="button">Double</button>
```

Comment: @RohitPatel No, this is not a `return *` statement.